# send and receive json data from jquery , php

Tags: javascript, php, json

I working on google sign in with JavaScript , if user signed in with google  I will get his basic information as json data and send this data to php script , this script will insert user into my sql database 
but I don't know how can I retrieve json data which is sending by jquery in php 
this is my jquery code

```
  function update_user_data(response) 
  {
 var dataString = JSON.stringify(response);

alert(dataString);

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {myData:response},
        url: 'Save.php?id=check_user',
        success: function(msg) {var msgs=JSON.stringify(msg);
        alert(msg);
    //  var array = msg.split(',');
    //  var email =array[0];alert(email);
   //var password = array[1];alert(password);
   //$('#username').val(email);$('#password').val(password);
 // document.getElementById("modal4c").click();
        },
           error: function(msg) {alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
    alert(msg);

        }
  });
 }
```

you can see that I send the json string to Save.php?id=check_user

here is th save.php code

```
$obj = $_POST['myData'];

echo $obj['id'];
```

the json data which I send by javascript is like this

```
"{\"kind\":\"plus#person\",\"etag\":\"\\\"EhMivDE25UywestNG8tqFM2v- 
 A/ExECAGokGQl1532fQP_aRYY\\\"\",\"gender\":\"male\",\"emails\": 
 \"objectType\":\ 
"person\",\"id\":\"23229164823262432640\",\"displayName\":\"mohamad 
 buvaydanı\",\"name\":{\"familyName\":\"buvaydanı\",\"givenName\":\"mohadmad\"},\"url\":\"https://plus.google.com/1128891s326438205624449640\",\"image\"
```

}

but the php script reply with "{" message only

Comment: You need to decode data - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
Like $obj = json_decode($_POST['myData']);

Comment: You are not sending your json to the server, you are sending `response`. You need to send `dataString` and decode it on the receiving end.

Answer (score 0):

There is not `id` in your data. you passing `data: {myData:response},` only. your data should be like `data: {id:123, myData:response},` and you have to decode it first in php file because it is json format, not array. `json_decode($_POST, true);`

Comment: response is json data which contain                                                                    "{\"kind\":\"plus#person\",\"etag\":\"\\\"EhMivDE25UywestNG8tqFM2v- 
 A/ExECAGokGQl1532fQP_aRYY\\\"\",\"gender\":\"male\",\"emails\": 
 \"objectType\":\ 
"person\",\"id\":\"23229164823262432640\",\"displayName\":\"mohamad 
 buvaydanı\",\"name\":{\"familyName\":\"buvaydanı\",\"givenName\":\"mohadmad\"},\"url\":\"https://plus.google.com/1128891s326438205624449640\",\"image\"

Comment: @Maj.jad Can you just console.log(response); before calling JSON.stringify?

Comment: ohh..  but your data is not in JSON format. first simplify it. [json formater](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) open it and check your JSON.